# Eclipse-no launcher activity found

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am having a problem with this.

When I run my app in the emulator, the console says that no launcher activity found when I already add one in the xml file. 
Here is the `console log`

```
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] ------------------------------
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] Android Launch!
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] adb is running normally.
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] No Launcher activity found!
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] Performing sync
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyAndroid'
[2015-11-17 22:13:51 - Kamus2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyAndroid'
[2015-11-17 22:14:00 - Kamus2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2015-11-17 22:14:00 - Kamus2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2015-11-17 22:16:08 - Kamus2] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-11-17 22:16:08 - Kamus2] Uploading Kamus2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-11-17 22:16:08 - Kamus2] Installing Kamus2.apk...
[2015-11-17 22:17:50 - Kamus2] Success!
[2015-11-17 22:17:51 - Kamus2] \Kamus2\bin\Kamus2.apk installed on device
[2015-11-17 22:17:51 - Kamus2] Done!
```

and here is the `androidmanifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.han"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

                <activity android:name="Translate" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_TRANSLATE" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    </activity>

                     <activity android:name="Insert" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_INSERT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    </activity>

                          <activity android:name="Delete" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_DELETE" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    </activity>

                               <activity android:name="Help" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_HELP" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Really appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Your targetsdkversion missing